# std::for_each signature and type specifications of parameters

Tags: c++

Please explain how someone should reason to deduce 
the type specifications of the _Func parameter of std::for_each?

Motivation behind the questions is to understand the type requirements from method signature.

```
template<class _InIt, class _Fn1> inline
_Fn1 for_each(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _Fn1 _Func) {
    _DEBUG_RANGE(_First, _Last);
    _DEBUG_POINTER(_Func);
    _For_each(_Unchecked(_First), _Unchecked(_Last), _Func);

    return (_STD move(_Func));
}
```

Comment: Uh, I think you need better English. I'm really not sure what you're asking.

Comment: "...how someone should reason to deduce the type specifications..."? Sorry, but I do not understand the question.

Comment: Looks quite clear to me and I'm not even a native speaker. The OP asks about the way of thinking; how to approach the task of reading such signature

Comment: Basically, don't waste time and go straight for the docs http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each

Comment: I don't think it can be reasoned out. You are better off looking at [some reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each).

Comment: I am sorry for my english. I will ask it again. C++ is a strongly typed language. I know perfectly well how to RTFM but i would like to hear from expert how type information can be understood. I want to understand what are the requirements from _Func. What is the signature that is expected by contract.

Comment: From the reference linked above, "UnaryFunction must meet the requirements of MoveConstructible. Does not have to be CopyConstructible", then follow links. These are templates, so the requirements can be rather conceptual.

Comment: @user1136478: What juanchopanza said. Remember that templates are resolved at compile time, i.e. you don't need any type hierachy as long as the requirements of the template are met.

Comment: @user there's really no way to discern this information from this signature without consulting docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular signature doesn't say anything about types at all. It's a template which will accept 3 arguments, 2of them being of the same type.

To see what restrictions are imposed on the types of input arguments you should read the implementation of `_For_each`, which I bet in turn will have two dozens of specialisations and delegations.

Reading STL source code is a sheer nightmare.

So, as suggsted in comments, give it up and go read the documentation.

Comment: Or for everything you should and can know about a standard library function, [read the standard](http://isocpp.org/std/the-standard).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at some documentation, and see the samples.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5sk9w9k(v=vs.100).aspx

Essentially, your predicate function should accept a parameter that is the same type as the `container::value_type`.

```
std::vector<int> myNumbers;
std::for_each(std::begin(myNumbers), std::end(myNumbers), [](const int number)
{
    // Do something with the number
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation of `std::for_each` from [libcxx](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/algorithm#L788).

```
template <class _InputIterator, class _Function>
inline _Function
for_each(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Function __f)
{
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
        __f(*__first);
    return _VSTD::move(__f);
}
```

Here's it fairly clear what the "contract" is for `_Function`. However, this is merely one implementation, and other implementations could more closely follow the standard, or allow other things to work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `std::for_each` does this:

```
_Fn1 for_each(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _Fn1 _Func)
{
  for (; _First < _Last; ++_First)
    _Func(*_First);

  return _Func;
}
```

So, as you can see, `_Func` is a function that takes a `*_InIt` and returns nothing (in fact, it can return whatever, but the return value is discarded). So `_Fn1` can be either a pointer to a function taking a `*_InIt` or a functor whose operator `()` takes a `*_InIt`.

Even though the return value of the function, if any, is discarded, if `_Fn1` is actually a functor it can have internal state that you can check after executing `std::for_each`. That's the reason why this algorithm returns `_Fn1`.

Comment: In C++11, the last line would actually be `return std::move(_Func);`, but I chose to simplify the answer a bit.